# How to make page preview popup like Wikipedia?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make Wikipedia like a link hover popup preview. I have a small issue just about design. I want to make a little triangle to the top/ left/ right/ bottom of any image. I have been searched the Wikipedia hover popup in inspect elements. There is nothing like `::after/::before` CSS Pseudo selector nor an SVG nothing else to render the triangle.

My Code

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#preview {
  margin: 2rem auto;
  width: 320px;
  box-shadow: 0 30px 90px -20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

img {
  width: 320px;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0.5rem 1rem 1rem;
}
p::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 25%;
  height: 20px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #ffffff 50%);
  pointer-events: none;
}

a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
footer img {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  margin: 0 1rem 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="preview">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8a/Plates_tect2_en.svg/480px-Plates_tect2_en.svg.png" alt="globe"/>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <p>This is a <b>list of tectonic plates</b> on Earth's surface. Tectonic plates are pieces of  Earth's crust and uppermost mantle, together referred to as the lithosphere. The plates are around 100&nbsp;km (62&nbsp;mi) thick and consist of two principal types of material: oceanic crusting.
    </p>
  </a>
  <footer>
    <img src="https://icon-library.com/images/app-settings-icon/app-settings-icon-23.jpg"/>
  </footer>
</div>
```

I want a triangle to my preview popup like Wikipedia. Here it is:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the wiki link?

Comment: OP means like whenever you're looking at something on Wikipedia, and they have a link to another Wikipedia page, when you hover over the link, it's what pops up.  Go to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plate_tectonics, scroll down to "Current Plates" section, and hover over "List of tectonic plates" (with the link in the upper section of your screen).  When the link is in the lower section of the browser screen, then the pop-up has its triangle on the bottom

Comment: Exactly, but how the triangle mixed with the image?

Comment: This is achieved using clip-paths. The relevant CSS section of wikipedia CSS is here: https://paste.rs/zfi.css

Comment: Play around with this: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: Thank you so much I got the idea. I don't understand How could I forget about this clip-path. :( Need to go MDN/ w3schools again :)

Answer (score 3):

CSS `clip-path` is a way to make it.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#preview {
  margin: 2rem auto;
  width: 320px;
  box-shadow: 0 30px 90px -20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

img {
  width: 320px;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
}

.set-triangle {
  --x1: 0;
  --x2: var(--pseudo-radius);
  --x3: calc(var(--pointer-offset) - (var(--pointer-width) / 2));
  --x4: var(--pointer-offset);
  --x5: calc(var(--pointer-offset) + (var(--pointer-width) / 2));
  --x6: calc(100% - var(--pseudo-radius));
  --x7: 100%;
  --y1: 0;
  --y2: var(--pointer-height);
  --y3: calc(var(--pointer-height) + var(--pseudo-radius));
  --y4: calc(100% - var(--pseudo-radius));
  --y5: 100%;
  padding-top: 0;
  display: flex;
  background: #fff;
  --pseudo-radius: 2px;
  --pointer-height: 8px;
  --pointer-width: 16px;
  --pointer-offset: 26px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(var(--x2) var(--y2), var(--x3) var(--y2), var(--x4) var(--y1), var(--x5) var(--y2), var(--x6) var(--y2), var(--x7) var(--y3), var(--x7) var(--y4), var(--x6) var(--y5), var(--x2) var(--y5), var(--x1) var(--y4), var(--x1) var(--y3));
          clip-path: polygon(var(--x2) var(--y2), var(--x3) var(--y2), var(--x4) var(--y1), var(--x5) var(--y2), var(--x6) var(--y2), var(--x7) var(--y3), var(--x7) var(--y4), var(--x6) var(--y5), var(--x2) var(--y5), var(--x1) var(--y4), var(--x1) var(--y3));
    position: relative;
    top: -9px;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0 1rem 1rem;
}
p::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 25%;
  height: 20px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #ffffff 50%);
  pointer-events: none;
}

a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
footer img {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  margin: 0 1rem 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="preview">
  <a href="#" class="set-triangle">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8a/Plates_tect2_en.svg/480px-Plates_tect2_en.svg.png" alt="globe"/>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <p>This is a <b>list of tectonic plates</b> on Earth's surface. Tectonic plates are pieces of  Earth's crust and uppermost mantle, together referred to as the lithosphere. The plates are around 100&nbsp;km (62&nbsp;mi) thick and consist of two principal types of material: oceanic crusting.
    </p>
  </a>
  <footer>
    <img src="https://icon-library.com/images/app-settings-icon/app-settings-icon-23.jpg"/>
  </footer>
</div>
```